# How to containerize an application with websphere-liberty image

Tags: java, docker, containers, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to containerize an application with [websphere-liberty](https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty) image

In my project i have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM websphere-liberty:kernel

COPY --chown=1001:0 target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /config/dropins/verificaciones/
COPY --chown=1001:0 src/main/config/server.xml /config/

RUN configure.sh
```

my server.xml is this:

```
<server description="Sample Liberty server">
    <variable name="default.http.port" defaultValue="9080"/>
    <variable name="default.https.port" defaultValue="9443"/>
    <webApplication location="demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" contextRoot="/srp-verificaciones" />
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="-1"/>
</server>
```

later i run this commands:

```
$ docker build -t app .
$ docker run -d -p 8080:9080 app
```

but i get no response.

is just a servlet with a hello world.

what am i missing?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the liberty splash page at 9080:/ come up?  If so, and it's the app that's not coming up, Checking the container logs might show something.  Depending what's in the app, you might need to add features to server.xml, for example <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>

Comment: @covener You dont need to use 1:1 port mapping in docker nor define virtualhosts. I have my liberty server on port 9080, and I can access it perfectly fine using -p 8080:9080 or -p 12345:9080.

Comment: In Liberty, the default virtual host (default_host) matches requests from any incoming host and port combination, and forwards them on to the default application container. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=liberty-using-virtual-hosts

Comment: Thanks @Gas deleted misleading comment

Answer (score 2):

There are several potential issues with your container:

1. You are using `kernel` image which doesnt include any features, so your `server.xml` would need to specify features you need e.g.

```
    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

2. If you use dropins then you need to put war file into that directory not subdirectory, so your dockerfile should have entry like this (without /verificaciones/):

```
COPY --chown=1001:0 target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /config/dropins
```

and if you use dropins and dont have `ibm-web-ext.xml` file in your `WEB-INF` folder, then app is deployed on the `context-root` based on your file name - in this case `/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT`

In this case also you CANNOT have `<webApplication ...` entry in your `server.xml`

3. If you want to use `<webApplication..` then your application should be put to `apps` folder, NOT `dropins` like this:

```
COPY --chown=1001:0 target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /config/apps
```

and in this case you can access your app by context root defined in that tag.
More details here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/base?topic=deploying-applications-in-liberty

So clean up your dockerfile, and if you still have issues, add full `server.xml` and logs from starting the server.